# SQL if else filter in single select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to output the following:

> for each group by personId, if email ends with '@company.com' then filter by [where type = 'h'] else filter [where type = 't']
>   so the query would output the following:
>
> 1 bob@hotmail.com    h
>
> 2 bill@hotmail.com   t

```
create table #emails (personId int, email nvarchar(100), type char(1) )

insert into #emails values (1, 'bob@company.com', 't');
insert into #emails values (1, 'bob@hotmail.com', 'h');
insert into #emails values (2, 'bill@hotmail.com', 't');
insert into #emails values (2, 'bill@gmail.com', 'h');

select * from #emails

drop table #emails
```

Thanks

Comment: Your sample results don't follow your rules.

Comment: If the email ends with '@company.com' get an address with type='h' else get the address where type='t'.

Comment: please share expected ouput

Answer (score 3):

This is based on the description of the logic, not the sample results.

I think you want boolean logic in the `where` clause:

```
where (email like '%@company.com' and type = 'h') or
      (email not like '%@company.com' and type = 't')
```

This particular version assumes that `email` is never `NULL`.  It is easy enough to incorporate that into the logic.

EDIT:

I see, this is a prioritization query:

```
select top (1) with ties e.*
from #emails e
order by row_number() over (partition by personId
                            order by (case when email like '%@company.com' and type = 'h' then 1
                                           when type = 't' then 2
                                           else 3
                                      end)
                            );
```

Comment: That just gives me: [2, bill@hotmail.com, t]

Comment: @AndrewJocelyn . . . I don't think your explanation is clear.  You are trying to get one row per `personId`, subject to prioritization conditions.  You are not merely filtering the data.

Comment: I think you are right. I will play with your prioritization example. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewJocelyn . . . The last query should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude `type` column from the insert and use a computed field instead, as below:

```
create table #emails (personId int, email nvarchar(100), type as case when email like '%@company.com' then 'h' else 't' end)
```

Like that all your inserts will automatically have the `type` column handled

EDIT: If you still want to perform an update after words just use the same `CASE` statement in the select.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to understand the question, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT personId, email, type
FROM #emails t0
WHERE type = CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM #emails t1
    WHERE t0.personId = t1.personId
    AND t1.email LIKE '%@company.com'
) THEN 'h' ELSE 't' END
```

This will give the desired results, so the text of the question should be something like "when there is a record for that person with email ends with `@company.com` then type `h` otherwise type `t`.

Comment: That looks better. I need 'CASE WHEN EXISTS'. Thanks

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right. Your `@company.com` is a default value to email column. So, you want to get the actual email, which will be the next email for each person. I'm not sure about the type column why you're trying to using it, as (in my opinion) doesn't matter if is it h or t as long as we can exclude emails that ends with  `@company.com` directly  with this simple query :

```
SELECT *
FROM  #emails
WHERE 
    RIGHT(email, 11) <> 'company.com'
```

from there you can expand the where clause as much conditions as needed.